# How can I do a CountUp timer loop?

Tags: android, timer, chronometer

I need a count up time to launch a task every five minutes and restart the count up to do the same task every five minutes.

I have tried it making my own custom countdown timer, but I do not know how to implement the loop

```
private static final long INTERVAL_MS = 1000;
private final long duration;

protected CountUpTimer( long durationMs ){
    super( durationMs, INTERVAL_MS );
    this.duration = durationMs;
}

public abstract void onTick( int second );

@Override
public void onTick( long msUntilFinished )
{
    int second = ( int ) ( ( duration - msUntilFinished ) / 1000);
    onTick( second );
}

@Override
public void onFinish()
{
    onTick( duration / 1000 );
}
```

And in my class:

```
private void initCountUpTimer()
{
    int SECONDS = 500*60;
    CountUpTimer timer = new CountUpTimer(SECONDS)
    {
        @Override
        public void onTick( int second )
        {

        }
    };
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: You can use `TimerTask` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few APIs you can use in Android to do that.

From the official Android doc -

When considering doing work off the main thread, consider three factors:

Can the work be deferred, or does it need to happen exactly when scheduled? For example, if you need to fetch some data from the network in response to the user clicking a button, that work must be done right away. However, if you want to upload your logs to the server, that work can be deferred without affecting your app’s performance or user expectations.

Once the work starts executing, should the OS try to keep the app process alive? For example, decoding and displaying a bitmap is something that only needs to happen while the app is in the foreground and the process is alive. However, a music player needs to continue playing music even when the app is in the background and not actively being used.

Does the work start in response to system triggers? These triggers could be things like network status, battery state, storage levels, and so on. For example, you might want to wait to communicate with your server until you are out of airplane mode. In this case, if the app process is dead, you might want it to be recreated once the device is online again so that you can perform your work.

Depending on these factors, choose your way of performing tasks

You can check which method to use [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/background) 
developer.android.com/guide/background

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop, just start your Timer again in onFinish()

```
@Override
public void onFinish()
{
    // Start again
}
```

Consider using AlarmManager, JobScheduler,... You should not try to loop like that, OS will kill your process